# JSP Multiple Buttons with Different API in Single Form

Tags: java, api, rest, jsp, controller

I was having some problem when trying to put multiple buttons in one JSP form.

```
<form:form action="/search" method="POST">

<tr>
<td align="left">
<input type="button" onclick="valSubmit('doImageExtractSearchList', this.form);" value="Image Extract" />
</td>

<td align="right">
<input type="button" onclick="valSubmit('doCardIssueSearchList', this.form);" value="Card Search" /> 
</td>
</tr>

</form:form>
```

In my controller class, how can I differentiate it comes from which button and specify the API?

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/search", method = { RequestMethod.POST })
public String doSubmit() {
    return "";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/imageExtract", method = { RequestMethod.POST })
public String doSubmit() {
    return "";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/cardSearch", method = { RequestMethod.POST })
public String doSubmit() {
    return "";
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe on click of button change the form `action` to that particular button value using js so that the controller will invoke only particular method ?

Comment: Do you have any example to set the API url in the js so that the Controller class can receive it?

Comment: below answer provided is also one way to do or else just use `$("form").attr("action","yoururneededtopassed")` to change action tag on click of buton

Answer (score 1):

Since you already trigger a function call on click , why don't you use the function to make an Ajax call to the backend api . That way you could provide separate url for the POST call depending upon the parameter passed into the jquery method like :

```
function valSubmit(value, form) {
var url;
if(value == "doImageExtractSearchList") {
  url = "http://something/search/imageExtract";
}
else if(value == "doCardIssueSearchList") {
  url = "http://something/search/cardExtract";
}
var form = $('#formId');
var data = form.serialize();

$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: url,
  data: data,
  success: function(result) {
    alert('ok');
  },
  error: function(result) {
    alert('error');
  }
});
}
```

Comment: @hyperfkcb No problem .

Comment: Hey may I check with you in this case, how can I extract the data passed along in the controller class and to be used with @ModelAttribute?

Comment: @hyperfkcb The `data` will be a query string by default and you could extract it as a request param . But if you want to you could use `JSON.Stringify(data)` for setting ajax data as json then set the `procesData `flag as false and set the datattype as json to send the data as json in request body as well, in this case use the `@RequestBody ` annotation to extract the data at backed.

Comment: @hyperfkcb Hope the answer suits your se case and you were able to resolve your issue, in that case please mark the answer as accepted.